# 3d clipping problem

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, projection

i'm studying for my final and faced a clipping problem, i tried to search over google and youtube but couldn't understand the method to solve it

[Problem's Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDfuz.png) 
[image]

this is the head of question:
- Run a test to show whether or not point p (0,1,1) is considered in or out of each of the following planes:  and the following planes he asked for clipping ( c1,c2,near,far )

Comment: How about including this method that you didn’t understand in your question so that someone might explain it to you?

Answer (score 0):

look at dot product of (a) shortest vector starting on the plane ending on point p and (b) the in vector for each plane.  If its positive, the point is in.  If negative, its out.